# ipyleaflet area of drawn polygon

Tags: coordinate-system, geopandas, area, ipyleaflet

I am trying to get the area of a drawn polygon in ipyleaflet with geopandas...but kind of cant get a propper result.

```
from ipyleaflet import Map, basemaps, DrawControl,  SearchControl

m = Map(basemap=basemaps.Esri.WorldImagery, center=( 52.497614, 13.404697), zoom=50)
poly_color = '#00F'

draw_control = DrawControl()

draw_control.polygon = {
    "shapeOptions": {
        "fillColor": "#6be5c3",
        "color": poly_color,
        "fillOpacity": 1.0,
    },
    "drawError": {
        "color": "#dd253b",
        "message": "Oups!"
    },
    "allowIntersection": False
}
draw_control.circle = {}
draw_control.polyline = {}
draw_control.circlemarker = {}

def clear_m():
    global rects,polys
    rects = set()
    polys = set()
    
clear_m()
def handle_draw(self, action, geo_json):
    global rects,polys
    polygon=[]
    for coords in geo_json['geometry']['coordinates'][0][:-1][:]:
        polygon.append(tuple(coords))
    polygon = tuple(polygon)
    #print(geo_json)
    if geo_json['properties']['style']['color'] == '#00F':  # poly
        if action == 'created':
            polys.add(polygon)
        elif action == 'edited':
            #polys.update(polygon)
            polys.clear()
            polys.add(polygon)
        elif action == 'deleted':
            polys.discard(polygon)

draw_control.on_draw(handle_draw)
m.add_control(draw_control)
search = SearchControl(
    position="topleft",
    url='https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?format=json&q={s}',
    zoom=5
)
m.add_control(search)
print(m._layer_ids)

m
```

...and calculating the polygon area with geopandas...

```
from shapely.geometry import shape, Polygon
import geopandas as gpd


polygon: Polygon = shape(draw_control.last_draw.get('geometry'))
polygon.geom_type

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(index=[0], crs='epsg:3857', geometry=[polygon])
print(gdf)
print(gdf.area)
```

if get it right crs should be epsg 3857 and the area should be in sqm but my results are not close to realistic...
did i get something wrong with crs?

Comment: Dont use EPSG:3857 for area calculations, they will never be accurate. Better use a local metric CRS like UTM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Part 1)

From `shape(draw_control.last_draw.get('geometry'))`, you get coordinates in lat/long degrees units. Therefore, when you create a geoDataFrame, the correct code should be:-

`gdf4326 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(index=[0], crs='epsg:4326', geometry=[polygon])`

And if you need it in `epsg:3857`, just do this

`gdf3857 = gdf4326.to_crs('epsg:3857')`

(Part 2)

Do not use `geopandas` to compute areas. Use `pyproj.Geod` instead. You can compute the areas of the earth surface. That is, using lat/long coordinates directly.

```
# Get the geometry from `gdf4326`
pgon = gdf4326.geometry.iloc[0]
# Extract list of longitude/latitude of polygon's boundary
lons, lats = pgon.exterior.xy[:][0], pgon.exterior.xy[:][1]
```

Use `pyproj.Geod` to compute the area (and perimeter) of the polygon.

```
from pyproj import Geod
geod = Geod('+a=6378137 +f=0.0033528106647475126')
poly_area, poly_perimeter = geod.polygon_area_perimeter(lons, lats)

# Print the results
print("Area, (sq.m): {:.1f}".format(abs(poly_area)))
print("Perimeter, (m): {:.2f}".format(poly_perimeter))
```

You will get the result similar to this:

```
Area, (sq.m): 3977.8
Perimeter, (m): 253.78
```

Comment: works great! thx! thx for the explanation!